# Hard Disk issue when connected to PC

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a sata hdd which is recognized in BIOS and startup, but throws an error for corrupted data when accessed from My Computer, but when I connect the disk to a device that has no RAM memory ( like older TV sets with usb or dreamboxes, cable recivers) I can access data on it ( pictures and videos )..is there any way to extract and recover data without formatting this disk.
This disk contains a lot of family photos and recording so, in advance, i thank You all for your assistance..

Comment: How did you connect it? If you use an externel HDD case then check if the drive is AF (using 4K sectors) and if the external case is 'trying to be helpful'.  You can check that by formatting a spare drive, putting data on it and then moving it to the caddy.  If not using a caddy, please also  mention is you go from internal SATA bus to another internal SATA bus. Use the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1233428/edit) link for this to add the information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would to be verify if you have a good connection between the HDD and the PC.

You should verify if the external caddy (if any), the cables (SATA or USB), and the USB port on the PC are functioning properly. For instance, the PC USB port might not be delivering the necessary current to power correctly the HDD, thus triggering errors.

Then, I suggest you try a Live CD like PartedMagic. There is a free 2013 version available [here](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/parted_magic.html). You can either use the included Linux file manager, the command line or some of the more advanced tools like TestDisk or ddrescue to transfer or recover your data.